# Tiled Editor map to optimization

Tags: java, android, andengine

I am using AndEngine to create a project game for school.

I am creating a Tiled map using [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/). The problem i am having is that i cant figure out the size of the map it should be to fit all devices.

or is there a way to create the Tiled map to fit all screen sizes? If so please let me know.

As of now the TiledMap is to small on tablet devices and on cell phones it is to large.

Any suggestions or tutorials on this?

This is what i want to create. Not exactly like this but it is an example.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in function for changing the tilemap resolution in Tiled.

Someone wrote a [script to change the resolution of a Tiled map](http://wasabibit.com/WasabiBit/Dev_Notes.html). This might help in making the Tilemap with two sets of graphics.

Generally speaking you should aim to support the two or three primary display resolutions. You may have to optimize the tilemaps for each resolution. An alternative would be to either display borders (assume a larger screen is as big as a slightly smaller one) or scale up the tilemap layer (that will most likely result in visual degradation). That means for the best quality you'll need to create one set of tilemap with the corresponding graphic assets for each of the device resolutions you want to support. There's nothing "automagic" about this.

Comment: Thanks alot for your response. So AndEngine responds to a different resolution for a particular device? If you are familiar with android

Comment: I'm not familiar with AndEngine but I assume it works like most engines. That means you'll have to design your game for particular device resolutions, and take different code paths depending on device resolution.